# Place a unicode character in NS_ENUM

Tags: objective-c, unicode, enums

When I try to place a unicode character in an NS_ENUM list I receive a warning for the following code:

```
NSLog(@"H\u2082O");

        typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Gas) {
            Ar,
            CO,
            NO\u2082,
            H\u2082O
        };
```

Note that `H\u2082O` and `NO\u2082` represent H2O and NO2 where 2 is a subscript. This works fine in an NSString but it doesn't work in an NS_ENUM.

Is it possible to include a unicode character in an enum or are enums restricted to strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enum literal follows the rules for an identifier - which is *loosely* that they must start with a letter or underscore and subsequent characters can be letters, digits or underscores.

"Loosely" as this has been extended for Unicode and the C Standard lists the allowable ranges of Unicode values allowed in an identifier and the subset of those which cannot be the initial character.

Unicode U+2082, SUBSCRIPT TWO, is listed as being allowed in C11, but cannot be an initial character. It is however rejected by Xcode/Clang 5.1. Other characters are accepted, e.g. U+2124, others rejected, e.g. U+2122. It would appear therefore that Clang is using a different set of allowable characters to C11 and you've picked one.

However why would you do this? This is just an enum literal, which like a variable name is never displayed/printed as its identifier in Objective-C. Typing `NO\u2082` has no mnemonic reading whilst `NO2` does.

So I think you may technically have found a bug in the compiler, but I wonder whether you are doing this for the wrong reason and think that the enum literal will be output according to its name (as it is for example in Pascal)?

Comment: I was just playing around with the new `NS_ENUM` and was wondering how unicode characters were handled. I understand that this is not exactly how enums are meant to be used but I was just curious as to why the unicode character wasn't working. Thanks for the explanation.